# What is the best way to find out salaries in my company?

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

I am a freshly employed software engineer in a young, successful company. I've worked here during both of the previous college summer breaks and that's when I negotiated my current salary. In exchange for experience I was OK with the offered salary although I expected more. Now I think I've gained enough experience to ask for a raise but I thought it would be wise to check out what are the salaries of others in similar position in order to be in a better negotiating position.

How can I find out what salary should I ask for? I guess it's inappropriate to ask colleagues about how much they are making - or is this normal?

Comment: If you're unsure of the culture, you could ask what they think someone else (say a new hire) is making. If they react badly to the inquiry, you know not to probe further.

Comment: I"m not convinced that this is a duplicate.  The other question is about researching typical salaries in the industry; this one appears to be about finding out what one's *own* employer is paying comparable people.  Glassdoor etc probably won't help you much with that, particularly if yours is a small company.

Comment: Have you tried implementing Multi-party computation ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your country's and more important, your company's culture. In some places it's okay to ask your (close) coworkers about their compensation. Usually though it is frowned upon.

Otherwise, [salary.com](http://salary.com) and [glassdoor.com](http://glassdoor.com) (and [others](http://indeed.com)) exist for this express purpose.

Comment: It's a small company so there aren't any records in such websites.

Comment: @PrimožKralj - You don't need to know what one particular company is paying.  You need to know what the market rate is.  Look at other similar companies.

Answer (score 0):

As Telastyn said is it okay to ask from your close coworker about their salary but I think you cannot get true answers by asking. Normally people not willing to share information about their salaries. So better way to find out the market price for your occupation.

Salary amount is depend on the country you are working. Some countries have published minimum salary rate for all jobs they have. So better to find out information from salary.com or any other relevant web site.